# Snowflake: same queries taking more time although using Result Cache

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jdbctemplate

I'm new to snowflake, Using JdbcTemplate for executing queries.

```
 BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
 dataSource.setUrl("jdbcUrl");
 dataSource.setDriverClassName(SNOWFLAKE_DRIVER_NAME);
 dataSource.addConnectionProperty(CLIENT_SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE, "true");

 JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

**Facing below issue on Snowflake:**

If I execute the same query multiple times, and **gap between the same two queries <= 150 seconds**, then it takes around **300ms**. If the **gap between the same two queries > 150 seconds**, then it takes around **1200ms**. These timings are from java code.
Although all queries are using a Result cache because I'm executing the same queries multiple times.

**Anyone have an idea, why is this latency is occurring if the gap between the same two queries is over 150 seconds?**

Comment: Have you enabled [JDBC logging](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#JDBC) and you see this in the JDBC log based on timestamp of the transaction? Also what is the time shown in Query History in Snowflake UI?

Comment: Query History showing around 100ms for all queries

Comment: If Query History is constant, then you probably need to look at the client side, so the JDBC log in DEBUG mode will show you more.

Comment: It _may_ have something to do with a transaction hanging on the db after performing a query (random hypothesis). You might want to consider making use of the `@Transactional` annotation in your service level code to see if it makes any kind of difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At Snowflake side, the AWS load balancer has 150 seconds timeout configured on it.

Network sockets are getting closed after 150 seconds of inactivity. This is why all subsequent communication attempts have to re-initialize the connection. That's why latency is occurring!